# How to take a list of partial file names and return a list of the full file names with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0, get-childitem

I’m wondering how to take a list of partial document names and return a list of the full document names with PowerShell.

I have ton of documents to do this with. We have a naming scheme: HG-xx-xx-###

The full naming scheme for the actual files is: HG-xx-xx-###.x.x_File_Name

I have a lot of different lists of file names like so:

HG-SP-HG-001

HG-WI-BE-005

HG-GD-BB-043

I'm trying to have program return a list of the full file names like so:

HG-SP-HG-001.1.6_Example

HG-WI-BE-005.1.0_Example

HG-GD-BB-043.1.1_Example

I've included both methods I've tried. I give it a list or even just one partial file name and I get nothing back.

I've tried two different ways and I'm at the end of my programming and googling capabilities, any ideas?

```
$myPath = 'P:\'


$_DocList = READ-HOST "Enter list of document ID's"

$_DocList = $_DocList.Split(',').Split(' ')


#Here I'm not sure if I should do it like so:

$output =

    ForEach($_Doc in $_DocList)
    {
    $find = gci $myPath -Recurse |where{$_.name -contains $($_Doc)}
    Write-Host "$find"
    }

$output | clip


#or like this:

$_DocList | ForEach-Object

{

gci -Path $myPath -Filter $_ -Recurse

       $info = Get-ChildItem $_.FullName | Measure-Object
       if ($info.Count -ne 0) {
              Write-Output "$($_.Name)"
        }
} | clip
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Doug Maurer's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64686220/45375) shows a solution based on a wildcard pattern based to the `-Filter` parameter.
Since this parameter only accepts a *single* pattern, the `Get-ChildItem -Recurse` call must be called *multiple times*, in a *loop*.

However, since you're using `-Recurse`, you can take advantage of the `-Include` parameter, which accepts *multiple* patterns, so you can get away with *one* [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Get-ChildItem) call.

While for a single `Get-ChildItem` call `-Filter` performs better than `-Include`, a single `Get-ChildItem -Include` call with an *array* of pattern is likely to outperform multiple `Get-ChildItem -Filter` calls, especially with many patterns.

```
# Sample name prefixes to search for.
$namePrefixes = 'HG-SP-HG-001', 'HG-WI-BE-005', 'HG-GD-BB-043'

# Append '*' to all prefixes to form wildcard patterns: 'HG-SP-HG-001*', ...
$namePatterns = $namePrefixes -replace '$', '*'

# Combine Get-ChildItem -Recurse with -Include and all patterns.
# .Name returns the file name part of all matching files.
$names = (Get-ChildItem $myPath -File -Recurse -Include $namePatterns).Name
```

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer! Sorry for the late response. This is working for me!

Comment: Glad to hear it was helpful, @pevin; no worries about timing.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
$docList = @('HG-SP-HG-*','HG-WI-BE-*','HG-GD-BB-*')

foreach($item in $docList)
{
    $check = Get-ChildItem -Filter $item P:\ -File
    if($check)
    {
        $check
    }

}
```

Comment: There's over 1000 files on this drive with the naming scheme. I just need to pull names from a list. The lists I have are over 100 documents long...

Comment: Thanks, but it still seems to not return anything. All the files are in folders so I added -Recurse, still nothing.

Comment: Interesting.  I'm not sure why it would not work.  I created a few files on my local machine and tried it and it did find them.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
$docList = @('HG-SP-HG','HG-WI-BE','HG-GD-BB')
$docList | Get-ChildItem -File -Filter $_ -Recurse | select Name
```

Comment: Thanks, but that would just give me a list of the over 1,000 files we have. I have 80 separate lists with 10-100 document names each that I need the full file name of. Thanks for the answer though

Comment: add version2  @pevin

Comment: You can only pipe in paths to `Get-ChildItem`

Comment: You removed your second example which was invalid, where you were piping in filenames.

Comment: @DougMaurer i remove example with regexp

Answer (score 1):

When using the filter with partial names you'll need to specify wildcard

```
$names = 'HG-SP-HG','HG-WI-BE','HG-GD-BB'
$names | Foreach-Object {
    Get-ChildItem -File -Filter $_* -Recurse
}
```

And if you only want the full path back, simply select it.

```
$names = 'HG-SP-HG','HG-WI-BE','HG-GD-BB'
$names | Foreach-Object {
    Get-ChildItem -File -Filter $_* -Recurse
} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have an established pattern of what the files look like, why not regex it?

```
# Use these instead to specify a docID 
#$docID = "005"
#pattern = "^HG(-\w{2}){2}-$docID"


$pattern = "^HG(-\w{2}){2}-\d{3}"
Get-ChildItem -Path "P:\" -Recurse |  ?{$_ -match $pattern}
```

Granted, there may be more efficient ways to do this, but it should be quick enough for a few thousand files.

EDIT: This is the breakdown of the regex pattern's hieroglyphics.

`^` Start at the beginning

`HG` literal characters "HG"

`(-\w{2})`

- `(` start of a grouping
- `-` literal "-" character (hyphen)
- `\w{2}`

  - `\w` any word character
  - `{2}` exactly 2 times
- `)` End of the grouping

`{2}` exactly 2 times

`-` literal "-" character (hyphen)

`\d` any digit 0 through 9

`{3}` Exactly 3 times